# Why is [0] === [0] false

Tags: javascript, types

If debugging shows that a variable is 0, then I think that I should be able to catch it with either ==='0' or ===0 but that didn't work. I had to use only == instead, then it worked:

```
var offset = 0;
alert("## DEBUG non_sortable_columns " + non_sortable_columns)
if (non_sortable_columns == '0' || non_sortable_columns == 0) {
    offset = 1;
}
```

I first tried this but it didn't work:

```
var offset = 0;
alert("## DEBUG non_sortable_columns " + non_sortable_columns)
if (non_sortable_columns === '0' || non_sortable_columns === 0) {
    offset = 1;
}
```

The value was [0] and `[0] === [0]` is false. How can it be false?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(non_sortable_columns, typeof non_sortable_columns)`

Comment: I bet it's `false`

Comment: String `+` value is very misleading, always `console.log` the value by itself without involving string concatenation.

Comment: First of all if you want to catch '0' or 0 then == is the natural way than such approach.

Comment: @gurvinder372 `[0]`

Comment: @Phil My problem turned out to be that [0] === [0] is false which I don't understand. I changed it serverside to 0 that I could test for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `[0] === [0]` is `false` because each `[0]` is actually a declaration that creates an array with the number `0` as its first index. 
Arrays are objects and in JavaScript,  2 objects are `==` or `===` only and only if they point at the same location in memory. This means:

```js
var a = [];
var b = a; 
console.log(a == b); // "true". They both point at the same location in memory. 

a = [];
b = [];
console.log(a == b); // "false". They don't point at the same location in memory.
```

2. `[0] == "0"` evaluates to `true`, because: 
In JavaScript, due to the nature of the `==` operator, when you compare an object with a primitive, the object will be coerced to a primitive, and then that primitive will be coerced to the specific type of primitive you are trying to compare it with.

`"0"` is a string, so `[0]` will have to be coerced to a string. How ? First, JavaScript will invoke its `valueOf` method to see if it returns a primitive, the array version of `valueOf` will just return that array, so `valueOf` doesn't yield a primitive; now JavaScript will try the object's (aka array's) `toString` method, an array's `toString` method will return a string that is the result of a comma-separated concatenation of its elements (each element will be coerced to a string as well, but that is irrelevant here), this would have been more visible if your array contained more than one element (e.g if it were `[0,1]`, `toString` would return `"0,1"`), but your array only has 1 element, so the result of its stringification is `"0"` (if `toString` didn't return a string but another primitive, that primitive would be used in a `ToString` abstract operation; if neither `valueOf` nor `toString` returned a primitive, a `TypeError` would be thrown). 

Now, our end comparison, with all the coercions and stuff, has changed to `"0" == "0"`, which is `true`. 
3. `[0] == 0`, mostly the same as #2, except after JavaScript has the string `"0"`, it will coerce it to a number, the result of coercing the string `"0"` to a number is the number `0`. So we have `0 == 0` which is `true`. 
4. `[0] === 0` and `[0] === "0"`, these 2 are very simple, no coercions will happen because you are using `===`.
In the first one, the reference (aka location pointed at in memory) held by `[0]` will be compared to the number `0`, this will obviously evaluate to `false`; 
In the second one, again, the reference held by `[0]` will be compared with the string `"0"`, this again, is `false`.

So, as you can see, good ser, all your misery comes from `==`, this operator, along with `!=`, are called "the evil counterparts of `===` and `!==`" by Douglas Crockford, for the same reasons which are causing your confusions.

Feel free to request any elaborations you might want and ask any questions you might have.

Additionally, see [this](http://2ality.com/2012/11/coercing-objects.html) article about object coercion, [this](https://www.google.iq/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjbqK-EvMbXAhVP6qQKHd4uDF8QFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FtoString&usg=AOvVaw12IDSpxHWO1TMqnznday3M) MDN article about `Array#toString`, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) StackOverflow question which outlines the differences between `==` and `===`.

Answer (score 1):

I just did the following test

```
var num = 0;

console.log("Number: ", num);

if(num === '0' || num === 0) {
    console.log("Num is 0 (===)");
}

if(num == '0' || num == 0) {
    console.log("Num is 0 (==)");
}
```

and got the output

```
Number:  0
Num is 0 (===)
Num is 0 (==)
```

Try console.log the value itself, if you alert or append strings to a number in JS it will always output as a string. This can be misleading when trying to debug code.

Comment: The value seemed to have been `[0]` which I couldn't test for so I changed it to `0` at the backend and tested for that instead. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `non_sortable_columns` might be `false`.
The basic difference between the `===` and `==` is that the 3 equals to comparison operator also checks the type of the variable, that means: `'0'` which is a string would not be equal to: `0` which is a number.

In your case the variable `non_sortable_columns` value might be `false` which means `0`in JavaScript therefore the value of the `==` finds it same as it doesn't check the type but `===` fails as it checks the type of it.

For better understanding refer to: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)